# In iplanet 6, where is the webapp directory defined?

Tags: web-applications, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my first war file on an existing iplanet 6 install, and the only place in the config directory that specifies what looks like the web app directory is in `server.xml`:

```
<PROPERTY name="docroot" value="/usr/local/ns-home/docs"/>
  <USERDB id="default"/>
  <SEARCH>
    <WEBAPP uri="/olc" path="/WWW/ns-home/docs/olc" enabled="true"/>
  </SEARCH>
...
```

But when I put my war file in `/WWW/ns-home/docs/olc`, nothing happens.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

There is a "webapps" directory underneath the server install directory, but that doesn't have work either.

Answer (score 0):

you need deploy war file thru iplanet admin console before doing this take backup of server,xml file

then campare backup file server.xml file  and currently server.xml you will understand